# Thinking about a part-time job despite regular full time status

Tags: united-states, part-time

Context: I have a full time job with a large fortune 500 company.  Everything is good there, not looking to change.  I am thinking about taking a part-time job (nights and weekends, maybe 20 hours a week) at a retailer I worked at in my college years, partially for nostalgia purposes but also to fund a a couple of projects I have going on.  This is all fine, but my regular employer, while not forbidding part-time work, encourages employees not to do so.  So my questions are:

- Is there some kind of database secondary work might show up on if they were to check, say, my credit report?
- Do employers check credit reports after you've been hired and work there a while?  Are they even allowed to?
- Is there any way I could get found out for my part-time work, other then running into somebody I work with at the retailers location?

Comment: Please add a location/country tag. There is no *global* database of your personal work history, but there might be way for your job to get to know you have a side gig in many countries. That obviously is specific to a country and you have not yet stated yours.

Comment: I'd guess there's a strong chance of somebody from your large Fortune 500 company spottng you working at the retail location before long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My response assumes you're in the US, and other places will likely differ.

In the US, there's no "database".  If you did a one time background check prior to employment with your regular job, they can't pull more credit reports without your consent.

Your employer discourages second jobs because of potential conflicts of interest, and ultimately because it's a benefit to them if your off-work hours MIGHT be more available in times of crisis.  They also don't like competition, i.e. you're less interested in your regular 9-5 because of the pressures of the other job or maybe even better money.

Comment: Here's a citation for the bit about the credit report: [Experian - Can Someone Run a Credit Check Without My Permission?](https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/can-someone-run-a-credit-check-without-my-permission/). There's also the actual text of the [Fair Credit Reporting Act](https://www.ftc.gov/legal-library/browse/statutes/fair-credit-reporting-act) but it is *long*.

Comment: They also don't want you so tired that your performance suffers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to show up on your credit report necessarily (disclaimer: I'm in the UK, they might work differently where you are) but I'd be concerned about the need to lie to your workmates. Maybe you're a lot more plausible than I am, but I'd hate having to make up an answer to 'Hey Joe*, what are you up to this weekend?' That's how I'd expect to be found out, not through document searches.